# Enable layer plugins when using external standalone QGIS python scripts

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18

I created a [QGIS standalone script (custom Application) that enables me to automatically export Atlas as images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289228/73088).

The problem is that in my QGIS project, I'm using a [Mask plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/) and the generated images don't take into consideration this plugin (even if I install it on `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins`) when executing my script in a standalone way whereas when I manually export Atlas as images using QGIS desktop and the same project, the plugin is activated and the mask is done correctly in the generated images.

I also tried to use the API `sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')` just after the `qgs.initQgis()` and also `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/lib/qgis", True)` (tested also with `/usr/share/qgis` andn `/usr` folder) before the `QgsApplication([], True)` without more success.

Is there a specific API to use when executing standalone scripts so that QGIS engine enables layers plugins?

I also [created an issue](https://github.com/aeag/mask/issues/71) on the Mask plugin project in case.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a reply to "Accessing QGIS plugins in Python?" question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11219/73088), one have to look at the source code of the plugin and understand how it is initialized and try to reproduce it in the python code.

[Another reply to "how to load the QGIS openlayers_plugin in standalone python script (not the QGIS embedded python console)"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114791/73088) confirms this:

> This is never, well maybe with some hacks, going to work well. 
>   Plugins normally use the `QgisInterface` object which gives access to
>   the QGIS interface and methods.  You don't have this object in your
>   standalone script.  Most plugins, if not all, are not designed to run
>   outside of QGIS like this.

[This replies](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40664/73088) confirms that this `QgisInterface` is created via a [C++ embedded python interpreter](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/final-2_18_21/src/python/qgspythonutilsimpl.cpp#L228) and I found it was created directly [from the C++ code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/final-2_18_21/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L864).

So inspired by [an other reply](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144182/73088), I tried to **create a fake `QgisInterface`**, then [init](https://github.com/aeag/mask/blob/1.5/mask/aeag_mask.py#L105) the plugin (thanks to [this hint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11219/73088)) with it and looks at its [`initGui(self)` method](https://github.com/aeag/mask/blob/1.5/mask/aeag_mask.py#L158) to only keep the non UI related parts required to make the plugin work.

Regarding the [Mask](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/) plugin, here is the full standalone python code to generate images from an Atlas composer:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsComposition, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile, QFileInfo, QByteArray, QTextStream, QSettings
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins') # need to add the path to the QGIS plugin, else the class of the plugin will not be found
from mask.aeag_mask import aeag_mask

projectPath = sys.argv[1]
renderingPath = sys.argv[2]

class FakeInterface:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
    def activeLayer(self): # used by multiple places in https://github.com/aeag/mask/blob/1.5/mask/aeag_mask.py
        return None
    def mapCanvas(self): # used by multiple places in https://github.com/aeag/mask/blob/1.5/mask/aeag_mask.py
        return self.canvas
    def activeComposers(self): # used by https://github.com/aeag/mask/blob/1.5/mask/aeag_mask.py#L403
        pass

class FakeComposer:
    def __init__(self, composition):
        self.compo = composition
    def composition(self):
        return self.compo

class FakeQAction:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def setEnabled(self, value):
        pass

def printAtlas(projectPath, renderingPath):
    # Init Mask plugin
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    fakeIface = FakeInterface(canvas)
    QSettings().setValue("locale/userLocale", "C") # Because Mask plugin uses QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")[0:2] which normally returns null in this script environment
    mask_plugin = aeag_mask(fakeIface) # Simulate the init call of the plugin from QGIS
    mask_plugin.act_aeag_mask = FakeQAction() # Because on_project_open uses self.act_aeag_mask.setEnabled(True)

    # Inspired by [Save Print/Map QGIS composer view as PNG/PDF using Python (without changing anything in visible layout)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164196/73088), [How to export a configurated Atlas with a python script / command line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/272839/73088), [QGIS: Automatisation de la génération d'un Atlas avec script python](https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=284842), [Search for "[qgis] standalone script" on gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bqgis%5d%20standalone%20script), [How to run a simple python script for QGIS from outside (e.g. Sublime Text)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29597/73088), [Using PyQGIS in custom applications](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-applications), [Generate a QGIS map PDF using python](https://gist.github.com/timlinux/486793ad61db4c1dec9d), [How to create a QGIS PDF report with a few lines of python](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/), [QGIS Server Plugin Filters: Add a new request to print a specific atlas feature](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-atlasprint/blob/master/filters/atlasprintFilter.py), [QGIS export “save as image” automate with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213065/73088)
    #Getting project as Qfile and the first composer of the project as a QDomElement from the .qgs
    projectAsFile = QFile(projectPath)
    projectAsDocument = QDomDocument()
    projectAsDocument.setContent(projectAsFile)
    composerAsNode = projectAsDocument.elementsByTagName("Composer").at(0)
    # Only way to convert a QDomNode to a QDomDocument root, inspired by https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164196/73088 & [Convert QDomElement to QDomDocument and vs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18868993/535203) & read the documentation http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html & http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdomnode.html .
    # Using a QByteArray because QString pointer can't be passed in python and QString is not available by default in QGIS python scripts [QGIS PyQt4 missing QString class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632169/535203)
    composerAsString = QByteArray()
    composerAsNode.save(QTextStream(composerAsString), 2)
    composerAsDocument = QDomDocument()
    composerAsDocument.setContent(composerAsString)

    #Now that we got all we can open our project
    QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(projectAsFile))
    # Loading mask
    mask_plugin.registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
    mask_plugin.on_project_open()

    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
    bridge.setCanvasLayers()

    #Lets try load that composer template we just extracted
    composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
    composition.loadFromTemplate(composerAsDocument, {})
    # Connect Mask plugin
    mask_plugin.on_composer_added(FakeComposer(composition))

    atlas = composition.atlasComposition()
    composition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)
    print 'Found %d features to render.' % atlas.numFeatures()

    atlas.beginRender()
    for i in range(0, atlas.numFeatures()):
        print 'Rendering feature %d' % i
        atlas.prepareForFeature(i)
        filename = atlas.currentFilename()
        featureRenderingBasePath = os.path.join(renderingPath, "dep_%s" % filename)
        print '`-> %s.jpg' % featureRenderingBasePath
        #composition.exportAsPDF(featureRenderingBasePath + '.pdf')
        img = composition.printPageAsRaster(0)
        img.save(featureRenderingBasePath + '.jpg', 'jpg')
    atlas.endRender()

    #Some cleanup maybe?
    QgsProject.instance().clear()


# supply path to qgis install location
#QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True) #already set in the right place "/usr" by default

# create a reference to the QgsApplication
# setting the second argument to True enables the GUI, which we need to do
# since this is a custom application
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

printAtlas(projectPath, renderingPath)

# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
# layer registries from memory
#qgs.exitQgis()
qgs.exit() # to avoid a SEGFAULT thanks to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153614/73088 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250933/using-exitqgis-in-pyqgis#comment441476_250933
```