# Calling a plugin (QuickOSM) from a Python standalone application?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, standalone, quickosm

I am trying to call the [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) QGIS plugin  from a standalone Python application and I´m not quite sure how to or if this is even possible.

My QGIS version is 3.10 (using OSGeo4W64) with the QuickOSM plugin installed.
Running on Windows.

I tried to achieve this by using QGIS Processing, but I failed.

```py
import sys
import os
import qgis
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

qg_project = QgsProject.instance()

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()

qgs.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

# The extent is calculated somewhere else
alg_params = {'EXTENT': my_extent,
              'KEY': '',
              'SERVER': 'http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
              'TIMEOUT': 25,
              'VALUE': ''
              }

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

outputs['BuildQueryInsideAnExtent'] = processing.run('quickosm:buildqueryextent', alg_params, feedback)

qgs.exitQgis()
```

This fails, stating `algorithm quickosm:buildqueryextent not found`.
When I try to call QGIS native, GDAL or GRASS algorithms, processing works.

I haven't found a solution to this. Maybe I can tell the script somehow where to find the plugin scripts? Is such a call even possible? Or do I have to do it another way all together?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is around here:

```
qgs.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```

Your are adding *only* QGIS native algorithms in your Processing. QuickOSM is a plugin and is not in the `QgsNativeAlgorithms`.

The way to do that might be differente since version 3.8. You should be able to do the `initProcessing()` function somehow, but I haven't checked.

```
from qgis.utils import plugins
plugins['QuickOSM'].initProcessing()
```

But I don't think it will work. (but it would be the best and cleaned way).

As a workaround, you can still do

```
from QuickOSM.quick_osm_processing.provider import Provider
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(Provider())
```

Note that you are in standalone executable. You need first to enable QuickOSM in your application. This is possible.

Comment: I've an uncomplete script to try to solve the issue at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/71def7a758bfa75425d5bc87dde68906
If you have any clue, do not hesitate

Comment: I will have a look to your script @ThomasG77. I think the plugin is not known by QGIS and needs to be loaded by QGIS. I'm not sure.

Comment: In standalone context, `from qgis.utils import plugins` followed by a `print(plugins)` returns empty dict (because no iface, so not automatic plugin loading I think)...

Comment: @etrimaille Thanks for your answer. I tried both your suggestions but both were not working right away. I´m looking more into this.
How would I enable QuickOSM for my application?

Comment: Either wait for QGIS 3.14, or have a look to this pull request to check how it is done https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/34617

Comment: You can have a look to this code. It's working well to load a custom plugin processing provider : https://github.com/3liz/qgis-lizsync-plugin/blob/master/processing/standalone_processing_runner.py

Answer (score 2):

I was going through the quick_osm code and thought doing this might work, which actually did! Please correct me if there is a better way.

```
from QuickOSM.quick_osm import QuickOSMPlugin
QuickOSMPlugin.initProcessing(QuickOSMPlugin)
```

You can verify the QuickOSM processing algorithms by:

```
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print(alg.id(), "->", alg.displayName())
```

-->

```
.
.
.
qgis:vectorlayerhistogram -> Vector layer histogram
qgis:vectorlayerscatterplot -> Vector layer scatterplot
qgis:voronoipolygons -> Voronoi polygons
quickosm:buildqueryaroundarea -> Build query around an area
quickosm:buildquerybyattributeonly -> Build query by attribute only
quickosm:buildqueryextent -> Build query inside an extent
quickosm:buildqueryinsidearea -> Build query inside an area
quickosm:buildrawquery -> Build raw query
quickosm:openosmfile -> Open sublayers from an OSM file
```

or,

```
processing.algorithmHelp("quickosm:buildqueryextent")
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289645/200728) did what I needed: Access the plugin ([QNEAT3](https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3) in my case) and run its algos in standalone. May not work with every plugin, but is not the big hack I was worried about.